# How can I use fetch in while loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My code is something like this:

```
var trueOrFalse = true;
while(trueOrFalse){
    fetch('some/address').then(){
        if(someCondition){
            trueOrFalse = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But I can not issue the fetch request. It seems like while loop is schedule many fetches into next tick. But never skip to next tick.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I will solve your problem if you post a jsfiddle

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: use `setTinterval()` instead of a while loop.

Comment: @ChrisG my money is on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Thank you guys. Very impressive answers. Will generator do any help in this scene?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`while(true)` creates an **infinite loop**, which will attempt to call `fetch` **infinitely many times** within a **single "tick"**. Since it never finishes issuing new `fetch` calls, it never gets to the next tick.

This function is very CPU-intensive and will probably lock up the entire page.

---

**What's the solution?**

What you are probably trying to do is keep fetching until the result satisfies some condition. You can achieve that by checking the condition in the `then` callback, and re-issuing the `fetch` if it is `false`:

```js
var resultFound = false;

var fetchNow = function() {
  fetch('some/address').then(function() {
    if(someCondition) {
      resultFound = true;
    }
    else {
      fetchNow();
    }
  });
}

fetchNow();
```

This way, instead of

```
fetch!
fetch!
fetch!
fetch!
...
```

...the behavior is going to be

```
fetch!
  wait for response
  check condition
if false, fetch!
  wait for response
  check condition
if true, stop.
```

...which is probably what you expected.

Comment: but if the condition won't be met within a finite number of loops, won't we risk in stack overflow?

Comment: No, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421769/recursive-promises-can-cause-stack-overflow

Answer (score 7):

Now with async/await we can use awesome while loops to do cool stuff.

```
var getStuff = async () => {

    var pages = 0;

    while(true) {

        var res = await fetch(`public/html/${pages ++}.html`);

        if(!res.ok) break; //Were done let's stop this thing

        var data = await res.text();

        //Do something with data

    };

    console.log("Look ma! I waited!"); //Wont't run till the while is done

};
```

Answer (score 4):

`while` loop is `sync` where `fetch` is `async` in nature, so `while` won't wait for `fetch` `async` operation to complete and going to next iteration immediately.

You can achieve this synchronously like following:

```
function syncWhile(trueOrFalse){
    if(trueOrFalse) {
    fetch('some/address').then(){
        if(someCondition){
            trueOrFalse = false;
        }
        syncWhile(trueOrFalse);
    }
  }
}
syncWhile(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The while loop fires off all the fetches before any one of them will reach the `then()`, so a while loop is incorrect here, even useless I would say.

You need to make the `then()` responsible for whether to continue fetching or not.

It also seems that your `then()`-syntax is wrong (maybe just an error editing the example). Furthermore you can omit the boolean helper variable (unless perhaps you need it in some other place).

```
function fetchUntilCondition(){
    fetch('some/address').then(function(response){
        if(!someCondition) {
           fetchUntilCondition(); // fetch again
        }
    });
}
fetchUntilCondition();
```